# Plotting a vector field using quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, plot

I'm trying to reproduce a 2D vector map with components

```
 v = 100/a * exp(-1/a^2 * ((x+0.55)^2+y^2))(-y,x) - 100/a * exp(-1/a^2 * ((x-0.55)^2+y^2))(-y,x)
```

and here are my codes. It did not give the map I want (see attached [vector map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqkjm.png)). Could someone please help me with it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

grid_resolution = 25
grid_size = 2*grid_resolution+1
a = 0.2
x = np.linspace(-1,1,grid_size)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,grid_size)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

vx = np.zeros((grid_size,grid_size))
vy = np.zeros((grid_size,grid_size))

for i in range(0,grid_size):
    for j in range(0,grid_size):
        x0 = x[j]
        y0 = y[i]
        xx = (x0 + 0.55) ** 2 + y0 ** 2
        yy = (x0 - 0.55) ** 2 + y0 ** 2
        expf1 = math.exp(-xx / (a ** 2))
        expf2 = math.exp(-yy / (a ** 2))
        vx[i,j] = 100 / a * (-expf1 + expf2) * y0
        vy[i,j] = 100 / a * (expf1 - expf2) * x0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(X, Y, vx, vy)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `vx` and `vy` are not defined.

Comment: Sorry I've changed it... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last passage, when you compute `vx[i,j]` and `vy[i,j]`, you are computing vector field components in `(x0, y0)`, while you should compute it in the current point, so `(x0 ± 0.55, y0)`. Moreover, you should change the sign of `vx` and `vy` in order to draw a vector field like the one you linked.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

grid_resolution = 25
grid_size = 2*grid_resolution + 1
a = 0.2
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, grid_size)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, grid_size)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

vx = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))
vy = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))

for i in range(0, grid_size):
    for j in range(0, grid_size):
        x0 = x[j]
        y0 = y[i]
        xx = (x0 + 0.55)**2 + y0**2
        yy = (x0 - 0.55)**2 + y0**2
        expf1 = math.exp(-xx/(a**2))
        expf2 = math.exp(-yy/(a**2))
        vx[i, j] = -100/a*(-expf1 + expf2)*y0
        if x0 > 0:
            vy[i, j] = -100/a*(expf1 - expf2)*(x0 - 0.55)
        else:
            vy[i, j] = -100/a*(expf1 - expf2)*(x0 + 0.55)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(X,Y,vx,vy)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm wondering why we should calculate in `x0+0.55, y0` or `x0-0.55, y0`.

Comment: The field formula is expressend with respect the origin frame `(0, 0)`, not with respect to _field centers_ `(0.55, 0)` and `(-0.55, 0)`, so you have to take that into account when you evaluate the field in the current point: the current point has to be evaluated with respect to the _field centers_ `(0.55, 0)`, and `(-0.55, 0)`, not the origin, so you have to add and subtract `0.55` to `x` coordinates of the current point